# Not able to Scroll through the Suggestion list in flutter type ahead package

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-typeahead

1. I have list of Countries in the List When I tap the TextFormField first time I'm able to see only few suggestion upto the screen size. Not able to scroll the all the suggestion in the list.
2. The suggestions is in the descending order. But I want it in acending order and should be able to scroll up to see all the suggestions

This is my code

```
TypeAheadField(
            controller: mrQuestionKeyNameAndControllerMap![list[index].keyName],
            itemSeparatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
              );
            },
            direction: VerticalDirection.up,
            emptyBuilder: (context) {
              return Container(
                height: 0.0,
                width: 0.0,
              );
            },
            suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
              return getSuggestionsForCountry(pattern);
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, String suggestion) {
              return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20), child: Text(suggestion));
            },
            onSelected: (String value) {
              mrQuestionKeyNameAndControllerMap![list[index].keyName]!.text = value;
              int countryId = 0;

              String countryName = mrQuestionKeyNameAndControllerMap![list[index].keyName]!.text;
              allCountryList.forEach((element) {
                if (element.countryName == countryName) {
                  countryId = element.id;
                }
              });
              districtNamesList.clear();
              allDistrictList.forEach((element) {
                if (element.countryId == countryId) {
                  districtNamesList.add(element.districtName);
                }
              });

              setState(() {});
            },
          )
```

**Update :**

I have using nested scroll view so that the scroll is not working.

**Solution :**

After Assigning scrollController for each scrollviews I'm able to do it.